# Create/publish Drupal Docker container of existing site

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose

I need to create a bunch of Docker containers of Drupal sites, one site per container. [From this list](https://groups.drupal.org/files/drupal%20sites.html), let's choose www.worldbank.org and www.wfp.org .

I then need to be able to push these containers to Docker Hub so that other folks I'm working with can pull individual containers and play around with them as needed.

Now if I want create a container with an existing site (www.worldbank.org for instance), how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The container will only run a server? Well then you simply copy the existing files into the container and then upload that build to the hub.

example Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
# install what ever you need
# configure your stuff
# ...
COPY . /var/www
```

Comment: Hi leymannx - but AFAIK there are several config files/DBs associated with Drupal sites. Copying into `/var/www/html` would work for static html files but not for Drupal sites

Comment: Right then you have to extend the Dockerfile to match your needs. Install PHP, install MySQL etc.  Although that would go against the philosophy of Docker (you normally would provide one container per service) but I guess that's how it might work for you.